# Problem passing arguments to function in codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, arguments

I am using the CodeIgniter framework. I created a library called `common_funtions`. This library enables me to call a function in different controllers. One function in particular needs an argument, but I’m getting three errors when I call the function:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Missing argument 1 for Common_functions::time_ago(), called in \...\get_comments.php on line 11 and defined
Filename: libraries/Common_functions.php
Line Number: 20

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: time
Filename: libraries/Common_functions.php
Line Number: 26

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: time
Filename: libraries/Common_functions.php
Line Number: 39
```

Here is my code:
In the library: common_functions.php

```
// The following function calculates ‘how long ago’
function time_ago($time)
{       
    $periods = array('second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day');
    $lengths = array('60', '60', '24', '7');
    $tense = 'ago';
    $now = time();
    $time_diff = $now - $time;
    for ($j = 0; $time_diff >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++)
    {
        $time_diff /= $lengths[$j];
    }
    $time_diff = round($time_diff);
    if ($time_diff != 1)
    {
        $periods[$j].='s';
    }
    if ($time_diff > 7 && $periods[$j] == 'days')
    {
        $time_ago = date("l dS F, Y", $time);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $time_ago = $time_diff." ".$periods[$j]." ago";
    }
    return $time_ago;
}
```

In my controller:

```
$query = $this->db->query(“
    SELECT * 
    FROM post_comments 
    WHERE p_id = ‘$id’ 
    ORDER BY date ASC”);
$comments = $query->result_array();
foreach ($comments as $comment)
{
    $comment['date'] = $this->common_functions->time_ago($comment['date']);
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Or maybe it’s a bug in my framework?
This is not the first time I’m experiencing this.

Comment: Put a `var_dump($comment)` in your foreach. If it's returning the way you want, it should print an array. Post an instance of what it's printing (just need one of the printouts, since it will print however many times your code goes through the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded the library with `$this->load->library('common_functions');`?

Also it seems in this situation, you would be more suited to use a model rather than a library, see: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html